# How to register types in the main container, but resolve in a child container?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, unity-container

I have a unity container and use `RegisterType` to register the following repository and implementer using `ContainerControlledLifetimeManager`.

```
public interface IPersonRepository
{
  Person GetByID(ObjectSpace objectSpace, int id);
}
```

Using this pattern I am able to have multiple threads (it's a web app) using the same repository instance at the same time despite the fact that each thread is using a different `ObjectSpace` (which is a local cache + mechanism for fetching objects from the DB + a unit of work etc).  But this makes me feel "dirty", and not the good kind :-)

What I would really like is:

```
public interface IPersonRepository
{
  Person GetByID(int id);
}
```

To achieve this I would have to create a child container and use `RegisterInstance` to register my `ObjectSpace`. This would work fine as long as I either:

1. Register `IPersonRepository` in the child container instead
2. Change the lifetime manager to `TransientLifetimeManager`

I don't want to do either. (1) Would just be too much work, I want to register once in the parent container and then no more. (2) Would work but if there are a lot of dependencies then all of these would have to be transient too and this would result in a lot of instances being created every time I needed the person repository.

So my question is: Is there a way to register the type in the parent, but to have a container lifetime instance resolved and stored in the child container instead of the parent container?  Maybe there is a way using a custom lifetime manager or something?

What I would like to achieve is this:

```
UnityContainer unityContainer = new UnityContainer();
//Might be a custom manager or something
unityContainer.RegisterType<IPersonRepository, PersonRepository>
  (new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager()); 
using (var childContainer = unityContainer.CreateChildContainer())
{
    childContainer.RegisterInstance<ObjectSpace>(new MyObjectSpace());
    //01 Resolves a new instance inside the child container
    var repository = childContainer.Resolve<IPersonRepository>();
    //02 resolves same instance as 01
    repository = childContainer.Resolve<IPersonRepository>();
}

using (var childContainer = unityContainer.CreateChildContainer())
{
    childContainer.RegisterInstance<ObjectSpace>(new MyObjectSpace());
    //03 Resolves a new instance inside the child container
    var repository = childContainer.Resolve<IPersonRepository>();
    //04 resolves same instance as 03
    repository = childContainer.Resolve<IPersonRepository>(); //Resolves the same instance
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since asking the question a new `HierarchicalLifetimeManager` has been added to Unity, this should be used when registering the type.