# How to register type in a container, but resolve in a child container?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, unity-container

firstly, I know there is question with similar title, but either it doesn't answer my case or I do not know how to utilize it ([How to register types in the main container, but resolve in a child container?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/530405/how-to-register-types-in-the-main-container-but-resolve-in-a-child-container)).

Basically I wanted to register my type in main Unity container, but I want it to be resolved against another child container. Let's look at following example (this is simplified example just to show what I am talking about)

```
public interface ICommonInterface
{
    string Name { get; }
}

public class CommonImplementation : ICommonInterface
{
    public string Name { get; }
    public CommonImplementation(string name) // this is the dependency that will be bound in Unity container 
    {
        Name = name;
    }
}
public interface IModule {}
public class ModuleA : IModule
{
    public ModuleA(ICommonInterface c)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"[ModuleA] Got interface: " + c.Name);
    }
}

public class ModuleB : IModule
{
    public ModuleB(ICommonInterface c)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"[ModuleB] Got interface: " + c.Name);
    }
}
```

So I have two completely separate modules, which depends on the same `ICommonInterface`. And this is register/resolve part:

```
// registration
IUnityContainer container = new UnityContainer();

var child1 = container.CreateChildContainer();
var child2 = container.CreateChildContainer();

child1.RegisterInstance(typeof(string), "module 1");
child2.RegisterInstance(typeof(string), "module 2");

child1.RegisterSingleton(typeof(ICommonInterface), typeof(CommonImplementation));
child2.RegisterSingleton(typeof(ICommonInterface), typeof(CommonImplementation));

container.RegisterSingleton<IModule, ModuleA>("ModuleA"); // I want to register in container, but resolve in child1
container.RegisterSingleton<IModule, ModuleB>("ModuleB"); // I want to register in container, but resolve in child2

// resolving
container.Resolve<IEnumerable<IModule>>().ToList(); // this doesn't work, because this is resolved in `container`, which doesn't have ICommonInterface implementation
```

So I want to register `ICommonInterface` as singleton, **however** each modules should receive its own singleton. What is more, each of those singletons have to be resolved in different child containers, because as you can see on the snippet, I bind specific `string` in each child container respectively.

This code of course doesn't work now, because `ModuleA/ModuleB` are resolved in main container, which doesn't have `ICommonInterface` implementation.

I either cannot use **HierarchicalLifetimeManager** or I do not know how to use it in my case.

Yes, this example can be designed in completely different way to solve it, the thing is in my real application, the class and dependency hierarchy is much bigger and I do not see other solution than "register module in main container, but resolve in child one".

#### Workaround that doesn't really work for me

So there is one workaround that I can think of - to register Modules in their child containers and then instantly register instance in main container.

```
child1.RegisterSingleton<ModuleA, ModuleA>();
child2.RegisterSingleton<ModuleB, ModuleB>();
        
container.RegisterInstance<IModule>("ModuleA", child1.Resolve<ModuleA>());
container.RegisterInstance<IModule>("ModuleB", child2.Resolve<ModuleB>());
```

This work for this simple, but doesn't work in my real application, because during registration of the module, some dependencies are still NOT registered, so I cannot resolve at that point.

Is it possible to do in Unity?

Comment: Another work around can be, to pass the resolver into the classes and resolve internally. I know, it's dirty